# What is the need of \xhh in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex

While learning Python from scratch, I found that there is a hex value for letters, but I don't find what is this used for.

What is the benefit of `\xhh`?

Comment: It allows you to enter character that you can't easily type, or which don't have a visible representation.

Comment: Thanks but sorry what you meant by character I can't easily type?

Comment: `\xhh` lets you enter byte values for characters that don't necessary appear on your keyboard.

Comment: It's useful for control characters and entering characters by their Unicode code points. It's also useful in byte strings for creating binary data.